# jQuery mobile navigation to full website breaks

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile to show a modified content of my database driven to the user, and in that mobile version I have a link to the full website, but whenever I click on it the AJAX loader image continues to load all the time and I am blocked in mobile version. 
I use a PHP `header("url: ....");` redirection.

Comment: How does the link look? Show some html or script

Comment: Should you not use `header('Location: ...');`

Comment: You're trying to redirect via php, but calling it using ajax? That won't work.

Comment: @mplungjan The problem is solved using the attribute data-ajax="false" <a href="..." data-ajax="false">Back to full version</a>

Comment: That makes sense. Post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved using the attribute data-ajax="false" `<a href="..." data-ajax="false">Back to full version</a>`